# Clear stack backstack activities before starting new activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I have android activity flow somewhat like

A->B->A

Moving from A to B and from B to A using intent and finish Activity B. On when I click on backpress I again go to activity A instead of exit from application.

I tried to set `Intent Flags` but was not able to achieve it.

Here is code to move from Activity A -> Activity B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If here I backpress than I need to go to activity A again

From Activity B -> Activity A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

But when I backpress from here I need to exit the application

Answer (score 0):

To go from B to A you don't need to do anything. If the user presses the BACK key, the default implementation calls `finish()` on B which will return the user to A.

If you have provided a button or something in B to go back to A, just call `finish()`.